# Deploying React app on Ubuntu 18.04: build failed because process exited too early

Tags: npm, create-react-app, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to deploy my React app on an Ubuntu 18.04 virtual machine provided by Digital Ocean. Here's my process: I have a git repo linked to the correct directory so all I need to do is a git pull followed by a 'npm run build'. Up until now, this has worked well enough and I could check the site on [my_domain]:8080, which is sufficient for now since I'm still in production.

However, when I tried to run 'npm run build' yesterday, I got this error:

[image: screenshot of terminal]

I've looked it up a bit but there's so many different possibilities that it's just confusing me more. The most common issue seems to be a lack of memory on the system, but judging by the data I get when I start up the terminal, this can't be the case.

[image: screenshot of terminal]

I have no clue how to proceed but I've also honestly just been starting to use DigitalOcean or Ubuntu for half a year and this is my first React app, so I would very much appreciate an explanation like I'm five ;)

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem was apparently in the amount of RAM I had available. Solution: memory swapping. I followed this tutorial and after doing all this, the problem resolved itself.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to sort out the situation in your case.

#### 1. Change the memory allocaction from node.

You can achieve this by doing so: run the command
`node index.js --max-old-space-size=8000`. This settings may not be persitent and you would wanna use a much more long term approach, which is of course the second option.

#### 2. Change your swap space allocation.

Just like the article shared by @Jesse in the previous answer, you can follow that guide to change your swap space settings. it works like a charm.